# Windows Server 2008 R2 DHCP Server with multiple DNS servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, ip

We have two DC's running Windows Server 2008 R2. Each server has DNS running and one has DHCP running.

I have configured the scopes etc. and added two DNS servers to the configuration:

[image: DNS Server setup]

As you can see I have entered the two IP's .50 and .60.

When I try and test this (using a Macbook) I get given an IP address, the gateway is correct and the domain is showing as it should. For some reason though, I only get given one DNS server:

[image: Macbook Network settings]

To be on the safe side I double checked 'nslookup':

> danny$ nslookup
>
> > server Default server: 192.168.1.50 Address: 192.168.1.50#53

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: does a 'cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver' list just one or both? if only one have a full look at that file to see if there are any anomalies.

Comment: That results in 'nameserver 192.168.1.50', and /etc/resolv.conf just shows the domain and the one name server.

Comment: That's really odd, I have the same client OS but see both servers - have you bounced both client and server?

Comment: Ping works all ways, client > server1, client >server2, server1 > client, server2 > client, server1 > server2 and server2 to server1.

Comment: Sorry, I meant have you tried rebooting both the client machine and the dhcp server?

Comment: Just rebooted both and didn't make any difference, just tested an XP client and it worked fine so it's something to do with my Mac.

Comment: Damn, odd, looked on the apple forums?

Comment: Apologies in advance for having kept poor documentation before as I had a similar issue a year or so ago. Hopefully one of the more Mac gurus floating around here can help me out. It _seemed_ like my Mac would populate fields automatically if it had been on that network before. I had to do some weird steps/surgery to have it "forget" or remove all mention of the network (hosts file, maybe?). Only then when I joined the network again did it pull down both DNS for me. Also - when you click on Advanced > DNS, does it show only the one server listed?

Comment: I think I've worked out what I missed - I had added the DNS server manually which is why it then ignored the second one. A hint for future ref; if you Mac shows the IP's in grey then they are set by the DHCP server. If they are shown in black then they are manual entries.

Comment: Glad you got it working! That may have been the manual steps I was trying to remember; I haven't used Mac for a couple years now and my wife took hers to work so I couldn't check.

Comment: @dannymcc add your answer to the answer and accept. I learned something new about macs today. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've worked out what I missed - I had added the DNS server manually which is why it then ignored the second one. A hint for future ref; if you Mac shows the IP's in grey then they are set by the DHCP server. If they are shown in black then they are manual entries.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding them in as a scope option rather than just in the server option. -(sorry this was ment to be a comment not an answer)

Comment: there are server level options and scope level options - its just a matter of granularity, scope level sets for only that dhcp scope. have you also made sure you flushed your lease on your system so its not picking up an old one, also dont forget to reload dhcp on the server to take the new values and make sure nothing else is giving out dhcp

Comment: I have restarted the DHCP server, renewed the lease and checked that this is the only DHCP server with this scope. There is another running for IP phones but that starts at .201 and this scope ends at .199.

Comment: I realise scope options are just a matter of granulairity but scope level options superseed server level options and it is possible to set type 006 (DNS) at both so if they have been set with two dns servers at the server option level and only one on the scope level that could explain it. it's work a quick double check.